# Hyper-Vにおける仮想プロセッサ数の考え方について教えてください。

Tags: windows, ハードウェア

**■実現したいこと**
Hyper-Vにて1台の仮想サーバーを立て、物理サーバーに4コアCPUを搭載したのと同等レベルの性能を出したいと思っています。
OSはWindowsServer2016想定です。

**■確認したいこと（CPU決定にあたって）**
（１）
近年のXeonのCPUは「8コア16スレッド」等、スレッド数がコア数の2倍になっていることが多いと思いますが、これはハイパースレッディングがデフォルトで有効である前提の数字なのでしょうか。

（２）
ホストOSに「8コア16スレッドのCPU1個」を搭載したとします。
Hyper-VのゲストOSに割り当てる仮想プロセッサ数は、物理CPUのスレッド数単位で割り当てられると思います。
この場合、割り当てるべき仮想プロセッサ数は「8」以上ということになりますでしょうか？
「物理コア数＝仮想プロセッサ数」ではなく、「物理スレッド数＝仮想プロセッサ数」になるかと思いますので、ここで「4」を割りあててしまうと、4コア物理CPUと同等レベルの性能は満たせなくなってしまうのではと思いました。
考え方はあっていますでしょうか？

※厳密には「＝」の性能ではないかと思いますが、CPUを決定する際のおおまかな考え方として教えてください。

Comment: 「ソフトの推奨要件」のソフトとは何のことですか？あと、割り当てるべき仮想プロセッサ数はゲストOSが必要とする数を満たせば、少ない方が良いのは明らかです。

Comment: 「ソフトの推奨要件」とは、「■実現したいこと」項目に記載いたしました「クアッドコア以上推奨」を示しております。おっしゃる通りライセンス等いろいろ考慮しますと必要最低限の割り当てにするべきかと思いますが、今回はそもそもの「割り当てる数の考え方」を伺いたい次第です。「物理CPUと仮想プロセッサ数の比率」と言えばいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「クアッドコア以上推奨のソフト」が何を意味するかは、そのソフトウェアの説明文書に書かれているのではないでしょうか？そういうドキュメントが無いのであれば、ソフトウェアの開発者か販売者に問い合わせてください。

Comment: すみません、論点がずれてきてしまっているので質問を修正いたしました。あくまで今回伺いたいのは、「物理CPUのコア数・スレッド数と仮想プロセッサ数の比率関係」の考え方についてです。

Comment: 一つ確認ですが、ほとんどのIntel CPU搭載製品では、BIOS設定などでハイパースレッドを無効にできることをご存じですか？最新はわかりませんが、事実、昔の製品はサーバー向けでもデフォルトは無効設定で出荷されるのがほとんどでした。ハイパースレッドがあるが大丈夫かと心配されるなら、購入予定製品でハイパースレッドを無効にできるかを確認された方が良いかと思います。

Comment: はい、BIOS設定でON/OFFを変更できることはネットで調べて存じております。ただ、「考え方がわからないから使わない」という判断基準は無いと思っております。正しい考え方を知ったうえで設計をしたいと考えております。

Answer (score 1):

（１）スレッド数がコア数の2倍になっているのは、ハイパースレッディングがONになっている前提です。答えはYesです。

---

（２）"物理サーバーに4コアCPUを搭載したのと同等レベルの性能"を出したいのであれば、仮想CPUを4個割り当てれば良いです。
上記は、物理コア8個に対して、仮想CPUを8個まで割り当てている分には性能の劣化は起きないでしょう。他の処理が入らないという前提です。

多くの仮想CPUが割り当てられ、性能を保証したい仮想OS以外でCPUを食う仮想OSがあれば性能の劣化は必ず起きます。

Comment: (1)につきまして、わかりました。ありがとうございます。
(2)についてですが、仮想CPU4個ということは物理4スレッド＝物理2コアしか割り当てていないということになるのかと思っていましたが、「4コアCPU搭載物理サーバ」と同等レベルの性能になるのでしょうか？
ハイパースレッディングで2倍に見えるようになっても、実際には10～15%程度の性能向上にとどまると記載された記事も見かけましたが、ネット上に様々な意見が記載されていて困惑しております。

Comment: 競合するゲストOSが無い前提であれば、大丈夫だと思うのですが、よく考えると私も自信がありません。資料を読み込むか、いっそベンチマークを取ってみてもよいかと思います。 https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-hyper-v-scheduler-types